# If the Head First Python quick_session.py (flask) code is good, is something wrong with my environment?

Tags: python, flask

I copied this test code from the book and also downloaded it from the book's site. It runs and when I enter "http://localhost:5000/setuser/Fred", it replies "User value set to: Fred", but when I enter "http://localhost:5000/getuser", there is a 404 error.

Since I see no errors in the code, is there something in my Python environment that is causing this? Here is the short bit of code. Thanks from a beginner.

---

```
from flask import Flask, session

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = 'YouWillNeverGuess'


@app.route('/setuser/<user>')
def setuser(user: str) -> str:
    session['user'] = user
    return 'User value set to: ' + session['user']


@app.route('/getuser')
def getuser() -> str:
    return 'User value is currently set to: ' + session['user']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

---

```
 * Serving Flask app 'quick_session' (lazy loading)  
 * Environment: development  
 * Debug mode: on  
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)  
 * Restarting with stat  
 * Debugger is active!  
 * Debugger PIN: 474-778-940
```

Comment: I copied this code and in my case the getuser endpoint returns the correct response. Check again the url

Comment: Something is strange. Immediately after using the setuser endpoint, I get "Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again." using http://localhost:5000/getuser

Comment: Yes that's strange, that's the usual flask message for endpoint that are not registered. But again, i tried this code and for me works. Only thing i can think of try changing browser, or use curl to test the endpoint and see what is the result

Comment: Thank you. I've never used curl, so I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to restart Windows. Then the code ran as expected.

Back in the old days we sang the tune "FDISK Format Reinstall Doo-Dah Doo-Dah"... Same song, newer beat.